# Can I make an object of android.app.Activity class?

Tags: android

Can I make an object of `Android Activity` like this:

```
Activity activity = new Activity();
```

If no, then why?

And what are the problems that I may face due to this?

Comment: no you should not. activity is started by `startActivity`.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from making an object of an `Activity` just that you can't use it as you would use a "normal started" activity.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I make an object of Android Activity like Activity activity = new Activity();

Will it compile? Yes. Will it work at runtime? Probably not.

> If no then why?

Because the activity will not have been set up properly. It will not appear on the screen, will not go through the lifecycle methods, will not be connected to the rest of Android, etc.

> What are the problems that I may face due to this?

A never-ending series of crashes.

To show an activity, call `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can do this. But remember, you will have an instance of an `Activity` which is not known to Android. So you won't be able to do much with it and it won't be shown either. You might need such instance if you write tests for your application.

In your application's code you should rather never do it. Android will create an instance of Activity when you start an by calling following method.

```
Context.startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivityClass.class));
```

Comment: actually i want to use sendBroadcast() from a class which doesn't extends Activity class. How can I do that?

Comment: @user2416657 you will need the activity context in the non activity class. pass the activity context to the non activity class constructor and use the same.

Comment: You need to somehow give that class an instance of Context. How are you going to call your class? From which component? There are Activities, BroadcastReceivers, Application and ContextProviders.